# Signing ClickOnce applications using mage.exe and Sha256 timestamp server url

Tags: clickonce, sha256, mage, rsa-sha256

Iam facing An error while  trying to sign clickonce(.application) with MAGE.exe and SHA256 RFC 3161 timestamp.

mage.exe -s /path/to/our/.application" -cf certfile -ti [RFC 3161 timestamp]

I receive the following error:

"Internal error, please try again later. Parameter is incorrect."

If I try to sign without timestamp or SHA1 timestamp everything works fine.

Can you please suggest the correct approach to sign click once applications using SHA256 RFC 3161 timestamp

Comment: I facing the same issue signing app and deployment manifests for an Excel ClickOnce add-in. Using the SHA1 timestamp URL, the signing succeeds, using a SHA256 timestamp URL, it fails with the same error. I have VS 2017 and .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: Commands:

`mage -Sign my-excel-addin.dll.manifest -CertFile my-excel-addin_Key.pfx -ToFile my-excel-addin.dll.manifest.sha1 -TimestampUri http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll
my-excel-addin.dll.manifest.sha1 successfully signed`

and then the failure case:

`mage -Sign my-excel-addin.dll.manifest -CertFile my-excel-addin_Key.pfx -ToFile my-excel-addin.dll.manifest.sha256 -TimestampUri http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp
Internal error, please try again. The parameter is incorrect.`

Same issue using -Algorithm sha256RSA

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved on .NET Framework 4.7.2.

.NET Blog - Announcing the .NET Framework 4.7.2
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/30/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-2/

See the area.
ClickOnce – Enable SHA256 timestamping of Deployment Manifests